# How should I secure an Azure Web App Excel Add In

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have an Azure Web App published that includes pages with Excel Add In integration using the Office.JS library.  We've secured the Web App using Azure AD authorization and it is working well as long as the user it logged into Office/Excel with the same domain credentials.  How can we allow our customers who are logged into Office with their companies credentials get access to our Add In site using credentials within our domain?  Federating the 2 domains would work but isn't an option in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure B2B to invite your customers as guest users in your AAD.

You could invite the user by using the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) as an Azure AD administrator.

Azure Active Directory > Users > All users > add New guest user

[image]

For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).

Or you could use the powershell:

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserDisplayName "Sanda" -InvitedUserEmailAddress sanda@fabrikam.com -InviteRedirectURL https://myapps.azure.com -SendInvitationMessage $true
```

For the details, please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-invite-powershell).

If you want to bulk invite users, you could create a CSV file, and then use the powershell to import it. For the details, you could read [bulk invite B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-tutorial-bulk-invite#prepare-the-csv-file).